# Maintaining the location of a view when changing its anchor point

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint, cgaffinetransform

I have a UILabel created programmatically and set with constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.trailingAnchor, constant: otherView.frame.width/2),
            theLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            theLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
])
```

I then wanted to grow the label onto the scene:

```
theLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0001, y: 0.0001)
theLabel.isHidden = false

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {
    self.theLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0) //or CGAffineTransform.identity
}, completion: nil)
```

But the label is left aligned, and it grows from the center, so I changed the anchor point to fix things, but that resulted in the label appearing further to the right than it should be. (I understand this is because I am now describing its position by the left side of the view and no longer by the center)

```
theLabel.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
```

I tried to just replace its frame and its center point after setting the anchorPoint (separately, I tried first the frame, then the center) but neither of these solutions made any difference to how the view displayed in app:

```
let oldFrame = theLabel.frame
theLabel.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
theLabel.frame = oldFrame

let oldCenter = theLabel.center
theLabel.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
theLabel.center = oldCenter
```

Any other suggestions or explanations to help me understand how I can effectively preserve the location of the view while changing its anchor point? Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach: save the label's leading constraint in a variable, and then change its constant to account for the change in anchorPoint.

You should be able to run this as-is. Tap the button to animate the label.

```
class LabelTransformViewController: UIViewController {

    let btn: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        v.text = "This is a label"
        return v
    }()

    let otherView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        return v
    }()

    var leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.85, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)

        view.addSubview(btn)

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(otherView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            otherView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
            otherView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            otherView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
            otherView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
            ])

        view.addSubview(theLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.topAnchor),
            theLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            theLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
            ])

        leadingConstraint = theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.trailingAnchor, constant: otherView.frame.width/2)
        leadingConstraint.isActive = true

        // presumably, you would start with theLabel hidden
        // but we're leaving it visible so we can see its original size and position
//      theLabel.isHidden = true

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // move the anchorPoint from the label frame's center (the default)
        // to the left edge, vertical center
        theLabel.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)

        // adjust the label's leading constraint by 1/2 of its width
        // to account for the anchorPoint change
        // need this in viewDidAppear so the frame is already set
        leadingConstraint.constant -= (theLabel.frame.size.width * 0.5)
    }

    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {

        theLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0001, y: 0.0001)
        theLabel.isHidden = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {
            self.theLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0) //or CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time here! For me it did not work in viewDidAppear because I had another line of code there that interfered, but using the variable constraint and adjusting it relative to the anchorPoint change is a total winner - I just had to run it at a different point in the runtime with how my project is configured. Thanks so much!